# fit-mave-plugin equivalent for slim

Tags: maven, integration-testing, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Some time ago I used FitNesse using FIT as test_system on my integration tests and on my pom file I had this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>fit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta-3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>src/main/fit</sourceDirectory>
                        <sourceIncludes>**/*Test.html</sourceIncludes>
                        <outputDirectory>target/fitTest</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now I want to do the same think but using slim but I cannot find any equivalent plugin for SLIM.

Does anyone know how to execute some Slim tests with 'mvn integration-test'? I saw that there is the fitnesse-launcher-maven-plugin but with this i need to get up a service and I want something like before that there was no need to get up a service using ports and all that stuff

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is just add a jUnit test to your project annotated with @RunWith("FitNesseRunner.class"), and in your pom file indicate that this test is not part of the unit test suite, and IS part of the integration test suite.

This actually works for both Slim and Fit tests. And can also be used to debug  fixture code easily (by just debugging the unit test from your IDE).

Sample Java class:

```
@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)
@FitNesseRunner.Suite("FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteSlimTests.TestScriptTable")
@FitNesseRunner.FitnesseDir(".")
@FitNesseRunner.OutputDir("./target/fitnesse-results")
public class FixtureDebugTest {
}
```

Sample pom content extract:

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- this test actually runs fitnesse tests
                         therefore it will only be executed for
                         integration-test goal
                    -->
                    <exclude>**/FixtureDebugTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- this test actually runs fitnesse tests-->
                <test>FixtureDebugTest</test>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In my own FitNesse projects I have a custom subclass of FitNesseRunner that requires less annotations on the class and allows the 'suite to be run' to be overriden using system properties (I use this on build servers to run different suites in different jobs without the need for multiple Java classes). This is part of: https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures

Comment: I've tried this approach but every time that I execute the command `mvn clean integration-test` the result is **Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0** but if I open the report one row of the test is failing.

Comment: I don't know whether this is relevant, but I always run using `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test`'. Are the tests compiled using your command?

Answer (score 0):

The fitnesse-launcher-maven-plugin can start fitnesse for you with its default port being 9123 so you can see the tests at http://localhost:9123/

The documentation is simple to follow and you could have the following configuration:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>uk.co.javahelp.fitnesse</groupId>
        <artifactId>fitnesse-launcher-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>set-up</goal>
              <goal>run-tests</goal>
              <goal>tear-down</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```